# Header's search path in C++

Tags: c++, header

I am trying to use tesseract-ocr api. According to documents, I can `include "tesseract/api/baseapi.h"`. The problem is the headers that "baseapi.h" includes include other headers like this `#include "platform.h"`, while platform.h is in ccutil file. There are many other files that include other headers with the same format (include the file directly without specifying the relative path)

The directory tree is like:

```
/tesseract
    /api
    /ccutil
    ...
```

How can I link all the files without changing the header files?

Comment: That's what '-I' is for.

Comment: @stark I will search for more instructions for -l option. Thanks!